Pthread (or threads) wait for any one thread to finish
I am using C++. I have a set of files to be processed by another program (Executable). I intend to run this process in multiple threads (not more than N threads to prevent system from being becoming unresponsive).
An overview of what I have:
pthread_id tid[numThreads];
gather all files into filelist
for(fNum = 0, tnum=0; fNum<NumFiles && tnum < numThreads; fnum++, tnum++)
    ptrhead_create(&tid[tnum], args with filename)
for(tnum=0; tnum < numThreads; tnum++)  /* This loop is waiting for all threads to finish */
    ptrhead_join(&tid[tnum]);

Here, if I run a loop upto numThreads and do a pthread_join, I wait for all threads to finish.
pthread is not mandatory for me. I am trying to use futures and promises also (though the code from copilot and gemini is crashing for me - mostly my prompts are not so good).
What I want to do, is whenever any thread finishes, I want to reuse that tid[tnum] and process the next file in it. When I did this for Windows, I used an API that was some thing like: WaitForAny. Now we are trying for a cross platform solution.

There is no cross-platform solution, unless you create your own set of thread classes that have a unified cross-platform API. The implementation still needs to use the systems non-portable native functions though.

Forget about pthreads. C++ had std::thread since C++11 (and that IS portable) and even beter it has std::mutex, and more importantly RAII objects for locking them. E.g. std::scoped_lock, std::unique_lock and std::shared_lock (reader/writer locking).  With these objects it much harder to create deadlocks/starvation due to bugs. Oh and for inter-thread synchronization : std::condition_variable, std::latch, std::barrier etc..

This is usually done by a thread pool fed by a producer-consumer queue. You start a bunch of threads, and put units of work onto the queue. Each thread, in a loop, picks up work from the queue and works on it. You don't start and terminate a thread for each file.

To illustrate what Igor said, herein, assuming file_queue and file_count are prefilled, then start all threads. #include <thread> #include <atomic> ; std::atomic<int> current; char **file_queue; int file_count; void dofile(const char *file); void * mythread(void *) { ; while (1) { int cur = current++; if (cur >= file_count) break; dofile(file_queue[cur]); } ; return (void *) 0; }

Try asio (former boost.asio) along with C++20 std::jthread or C++11 std::thread or boost counterparts.

If for some reason you didn't want to use a thread pool, then you could implement a new thread per task approach such as you describe with the help of a std::counting_semaphore.  Initialize it with the number of concurrent threads you want to allow.  Have the main thread decrement it as a precondition for starting a new thread, and ensure that each worker thread increments it before terminating.  There are various ways to ensure that all the threads get joined, or that you can detect when all have finished if you detach them.

@IgorTandetnik Thank you. Went with this approach. I now realize I was overthinking a simple problem.
